# Does scp require ssh server/client

Tags: ssh, scp

I previously had openssh-server/client installed on my machine. Doing

scp -r folder/ users@host:/location/ worked fine.

On my new installation without the ssh client/server fails. Do scp and ssh go hand in hand ?. Thanks

Update: Even a simple ping fails without openssh-server installed on the machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scp` is basically a simple file transfer "protocol" wrapped around `ssh`, so yes, without a working ssh client/server, you have no `scp`.

A secure file transfer protocol that does not involve SSH in any capacity is FTPS, also known as ftp+tls, ftp+ssl, or "FTP with explicit SSL/TLS".